# Help creating table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

[image]

Hi I am basically trying to create this table of contents. Every single content line has to hyperlink to a section in the text. Can someone help?

I also have this code

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,oneside,12pt]{article} % Creating he document class and telling the document to be off font 10

\usepackage{lipsum} % sample text
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} % to change headings
\usepackage{hyperref}

% renew \contentsline for toc to include hypertarget
\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline%
\renewcommand\contentsline[4]{%
\hypertarget{toc#4}{}%
\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}

% renew \section to link to the toc
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bf}
{{\thesection} \hyperlink{tocsection.\thesection}{#1}}
{1pc}
{}

% renew \subsection to link to the toc
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\bf}
{{\thesection} \hyperlink{tocsubsection.\thesubsection}{#1}}
{1pc}
{}

\usepackage{fontspec,libertinus,lipsum}
\usepackage{color}   %May be necessary if you want to color links

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue}
\pagenumbering{Roman} 

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\color{black}\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\bfseries}{}{1em}{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}


\begin{document}
\title{Alan Turing\\[\baselineskip]\normalsize Artificial Intelligence\\[0.3\baselineskip]} % Adding the title of the document
\author{Bilal Rashid} % Setting the name of the author of the document
\date{\today} % Setting the date of the document
\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage


\section{What Is Artificial Intelligence?}
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage



\section{Why Is Alan Turing Known as the Father of Artificial Intelligence and How Did He Aid the Development of Artificial Intelligence?}
\lipsum[2]
\clearpage

\section{The Turing Test}
\lipsum[3]
\clearpage

\section{References}
\lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```

But when this generates the page redirect but I on every page I don't see the title of the section and I also don't see the Contents section.
Here is photo to explain: [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Thank you @Mico

Comment: Have you tried loading the `hyperref` package with the options `colorlinks` and `allcolors=blue`? If not, do give it a try. Quick hint: be sure to load `hyperref` close to the end of the preamble.

Comment: I had it loaded and everything the picture you see above I actually coded that but now I can't figure out how I coded that I have been struggling with that for the past 2 hours.

Comment: Then please edit your query to post a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that generates the issue you wish to fix.

Comment: @Mico i kind of added a example and i posted my problemts maybe that helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in your example is quite complex. AFAICT, it doesn't achieve anything that can't also be achieved by simply executing

```
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=blue}
```

in the preamble.

For sure, the following code achieves your stated typesetting objective.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,libertinus,lipsum,xcolor}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=blue}
\pagenumbering{Roman} 

\begin{document}

\title{Alan Turing}
\author{Bilal Rashid}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\clearpage

\tableofcontents
\clearpage 

\section{What Is Artificial Intelligence?}
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage

\section{Why Is Alan Turing Known as the Father of Artificial 
   Intelligence and How Did He Aid the Development of 
   Artificial Intelligence?}
\lipsum[2]
\clearpage

\section{The Turing Test}
\lipsum[3]
\clearpage

\section{References}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```